# Uploading and displaying image with Cloudinary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, upload, download, cloudinary

I'm on Ruby on Rails, using both `cloudinary` gem and your their recommended jquery uploader by `//= require cloudinary`.

I'm using the following helper to upload

```
f.cl_image_upload(:the_image)
```

I think the uploading goes fine, cause I see the image in Cloudinary's control panel and a string gets saved for the `the_image` attribute, e.g.

"image/upload/v1412372928/wz2yv3w04xnaferfyqrv.jpg#c1ecda5de9194c1357ef800128b154ff9c7e5593"

But I receive an error image when I want to display the image with this helper :

```
cl_image_tag(@user.the_image, :alt => "Sample Image")
```

Cloudinary's image_helper is generating the following URL:

```
http://res.cloudinary.com/gnossy/image/upload/v1/image/upload/v1412372928/wz2yv3w04xnaferfyqrv.jpg%23c1ecda5de9194c1357ef800128b154ff9c7e5593
```

I have been following these guides:
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_image_upload
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_integration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carrierwave can get the value of the image and parse the relevant parameters. For more information about Carrierwave and Cloudinary:
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_carrierwave

You can manually use the [PreloadedFile class](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/blob/master/lib/cloudinary/preloaded_file.rb) to manually get the identifier of the image.
You can have a look at the [sample project](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/tree/master/samples/photo_album) which demonstrates both server site and client-side uploads with Carrierwave integration.